# node.js installation problem and apt-get update errors

Tags: software-installation, updates, update-manager

I have tried to install node.ks from [this](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-node-js-on-ubuntu-18.04/) instruction, but first installation part:
`curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_12.x | sudo -E bash -`

I get this output:

```
so@so-notebook:~/Downloads$ curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_12.x | sudo -E bash -

## Installing the NodeSource Node.js 12.x repo...


## Populating apt-get cache...

+ apt-get update
Hit:1 http://ubuntu-mirror.parsdev.net/ubuntu-archive bionic InRelease
Hit:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/team-xbmc/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease     
Hit:4 http://ubuntu-mirror.parsdev.net/ubuntu-archive bionic-updates InRelease
Ign:5 http://apt.izzysoft.de/ubuntu generic InRelease                    
Get:6 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease [1,811 B]   
Hit:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/alessandro-strada/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:9 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease        
Hit:10 https://repo.skype.com/deb stable InRelease                       
Hit:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/audio-recorder/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:8 https://apt.izzysoft.de/ubuntu generic Release                     
Get:12 https://mega.nz/linux/MEGAsync/xUbuntu_18.04 ./ InRelease [2,468 B]
Hit:13 https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian stable InRelease                    
Hit:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/daniel-marynicz/filemanager-actions/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:15 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic InRelease         
Hit:16 http://ppa.launchpad.net/freecad-maintainers/freecad-daily/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Get:3 https://shaggytwodope.github.io/repo ./ InRelease [1,031 B]        
Hit:17 http://ppa.launchpad.net/freecad-maintainers/freecad-stable/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:18 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease              
Hit:19 http://apt.keepsolid.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                  
Hit:20 http://ppa.launchpad.net/gencfsm/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease      
Hit:21 http://archive.canonical.com bionic InRelease                     
Ign:22 http://ppa.launchpad.net/gezakovacs/pdfocr/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Ign:23 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu saucy-updates InRelease       
Hit:24 http://ppa.launchpad.net/graphics-drivers/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Err:25 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu saucy-updates Release         
  404  Not Found [IP: 127.0.0.1 8118]
Ign:26 http://ppa.launchpad.net/hanipouspilot/rtlwifi/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:27 http://ppa.launchpad.net/haraldhv/shotcut/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Err:6 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 78BD65473CB3BD13
Hit:28 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/gcc-9.0/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:29 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/texlive/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:30 http://ppa.launchpad.net/linrunner/tlp/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Ign:31 http://ppa.launchpad.net/mank319/go-for-it/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:33 http://ppa.launchpad.net/micahflee/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:34 http://ppa.launchpad.net/morphis/anbox-support/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:35 http://ppa.launchpad.net/mosquitto-dev/mosquitto-ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Err:3 https://shaggytwodope.github.io/repo ./ InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 7086E9CC7EC3233B
Hit:36 http://ppa.launchpad.net/nilarimogard/webupd8/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:37 http://ppa.launchpad.net/noobslab/apps/ubuntu bionic InRelease    
Hit:38 http://ppa.launchpad.net/noobslab/icons/ubuntu bionic InRelease   
Hit:39 http://ppa.launchpad.net/noobslab/themes/ubuntu bionic InRelease  
Hit:40 http://ppa.launchpad.net/obsproject/obs-studio/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:41 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu bionic InRelease       
Hit:42 http://ppa.launchpad.net/openshot.developers/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:43 http://ppa.launchpad.net/peek-developers/stable/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:44 http://ppa.launchpad.net/remmina-ppa-team/remmina-next/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:45 http://ppa.launchpad.net/samoilov-lex/aftl-stable/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:46 http://ppa.launchpad.net/slgobinath/uget-chrome-wrapper/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:47 http://ppa.launchpad.net/stebbins/handbrake-releases/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:48 http://ppa.launchpad.net/teejee2008/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease   
Hit:49 http://ppa.launchpad.net/thierry-f/fork-michael-gruz/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:50 http://ppa.launchpad.net/tractor-team/tractor/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:51 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-desktop/ubuntu-make/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Ign:52 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:53 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntuhandbook1/lives/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:54 http://ppa.launchpad.net/uget-team/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:55 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/indicator-kdeconnect/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:56 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Err:57 http://ppa.launchpad.net/gezakovacs/pdfocr/ubuntu bionic Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 127.0.0.1 8118]
Err:58 http://ppa.launchpad.net/hanipouspilot/rtlwifi/ubuntu bionic Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 127.0.0.1 8118]
Err:59 http://ppa.launchpad.net/mank319/go-for-it/ubuntu bionic Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 127.0.0.1 8118]
Err:60 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu bionic Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 127.0.0.1 8118]
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu saucy-updates Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: GPG error: http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 78BD65473CB3BD13
E: The repository 'http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: GPG error: https://shaggytwodope.github.io/repo ./ InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 7086E9CC7EC3233B
E: The repository 'http://shaggytwodope.github.io/repo ./ InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/gezakovacs/pdfocr/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/hanipouspilot/rtlwifi/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/mank319/go-for-it/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
Error executing command, exiting
```

So i think there must be some problem in that part of it.

My OS version:

```
so@so-notebook:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
```

I have tried install it by snap from software application of Ubuntu, and get this output :

```
so@so-notebook:~$ node -v
v15.0.0-nightly20200617ee7f0e3f75
so@so-notebook:~$ npm install @tensorflow-models/posenet
(node:13944) [DEP0139] DeprecationWarning: Calling process.umask() with no arguments is prone to race conditions and is a potential security vulnerability.
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/so/package.json'
npm notice created a lockfile as package-lock.json. You should commit this file.
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/so/package.json'
npm WARN so No description
npm WARN so No repository field.
npm WARN so No README data
npm WARN so No license field.
npm WARN You are using a pre-release version of node and things may not work as expected

+ @tensorflow-models/posenet@2.2.1
updated 2 packages and audited 133 packages in 11.048s
found 0 vulnerabilities
```

But i like to know why apt-get don't installed it!?

Thanks.